# Azure app service using Azure AD from a different subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have a .NET Core application with a React app in it, and we've developed it using our Azure AD for login.  Now when I try to change the settings to point to a different Azure AD account, it runs locally, but blows up in Azure.  I found the application literally breaks with weird errors unless I change the GUIDs and other values back to use the internal Azure AD.

Is this a known restriction? Can I host an app for a client in my Azure and use their AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no restriction regarding this. You can host an app for the client and use their AD.

I just tested this by using a JavascriptSPA. I deployed this app to A subscription and use B AD settings. It works fine.

> it runs locally, but blows up in Azure.

Make sure you added the website url to your client AD as the redirect url.

[image]

**Update:**

You just need to change the clientId and tenant to your client AD info.

```
clientId: '{client ID}', //This is your client ID
authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}" //This is your tenant info
```

Comment: Thanks - it's blowing up before attempting the login.  My test at this stage is to see the client's logo in the Azure login, I don't have a login to their AD :)

Comment: @cgraus What do you mean of 'blowing up'? Have you changed both the clientId and tenantId?

Comment: OP, please share ballistic test results (error message from ADAL/MSAL/middleware) since blowing up is pretty common in the AuthN/AuthZ world.

Comment: Thanks, accepted although I had done all of this.  In the end I had issues with deployment, I had to deploy via FTP and set up the settings in the portal and it started working